# Connection timed out problem when testing on iPhone device

Tags: iphone, timeout, nsurlconnection

When i test my iPhone application on simulator there is no problem. But when i try to test it on iPhone device via xcode, connection:didFailWithError is triggered and the localized description of the error is 'timed out'. What can be the reason for the time out on device?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have an active wireless connection on your device.